# Edit global var and return it (or static var)

Tags: bash

I need to be able to modify a string of a global (or static function) variable and in the meantime return it.
I can't find what I'm looking for online...

---

To make the question clearer, in Python3 will be something like this:

```py
def get_static_variable():
  if 'val' not in get_static_variable.__dict__:
    # Some other code...
    print('Some other code test') # Prints one time
    get_static_variable.val = "Hello World!"
  return get_static_variable.val

print('FUN: ' + get_static_variable())
print('FUN: ' + get_static_variable())
```

And this works correctly...

```
Some other code test
FUN: Hello World!
FUN: Hello World!
```

---

In bash I tried something like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GLOBAL_VAR=""

function get_global_var(){
    if [ -z "$GLOBAL_VAR" ]; then
        # Some other code...
        GLOBAL_VAR="Hello World!"
    fi
    echo $GLOBAL_VAR
}

echo "FUN: $(get_global_var)"
echo "VAR: ${GLOBAL_VAR}"
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work...

```
FUN: Hello World!
VAR: *empty*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are always global, no matter where you first assign them a value, unless explicitly declared as `local`.
I believe the issue here is that `$(get_global_var)` spawns a sub-shell, thus the value "Hello World!" is only assigned in this sub-shell and never in the calling shell.

This will work:

```
GLOBAL_VAR=""

function get_global_var(){
    [ -z "$GLOBAL_VAR" ] && GLOBAL_VAR="Hello World!"
    echo $GLOBAL_VAR
}

get_global_var
echo "VAR: ${GLOBAL_VAR}"
```

This will also work of course, and I think it should be your preferred choice (don't rely on global assignments, just on returned values):

```
# as the name says, only "get" the value, don't "set" it
function get_global_var(){
    if [ -z "$GLOBAL_VAR" ]; then
      echo "Hello World!"
    else
      echo "whatever else"
    fi
}

GLOBAL_VAR=$(get_global_var)
echo "VAR: ${GLOBAL_VAR}"
```

Even better (I fiercely dislike global variables unless strictly necessary), make it fully functional:

```
function get_var() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      echo "Hello World!"
    else
      echo "whatever else"
    fi
}

GLOBAL_VAR=$(get_var ${GLOBAL_VAR})
echo "VAR: ${GLOBAL_VAR}"
```

Comment: Do not take into account the name I gave to the method, I really need to be able to set a variable and do something else if this is not set, otherwise, return the previously calculated variable..

Comment: Then the first option seems what you need

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution to achieve what you want to do is by using variable substitution,

```
GLOBAL_VAR=""

echo "FUN: ${GLOBAL_VAR:="Hello World!"}"
echo "VAR: $GLOBAL_VAR"
```

Here, if *GLOBAL_VAR* is empty(null) then the value in double quotes is assigned to that variable.

Comment: @Giuseppe I would personally suggest that you don't need to follow the OOPs methodology of defining getter methods.